# Delete all previously failed Jenkin builds

Tags: jenkins

I have a quite large multibranch Jenkins installation. I would like to automatically remove all previously failed builds on a branch if the current build passes. But I can only find the previous build from the current build.

How do I get a list of all builds on the current branch in post { success {...} }?

Comment: Not sure if this groovy gets you started - for a regular pipeline or FreeStyle job:
`job = Hudson.instance.getItemByFullName('MyJob')
job.builds.each {
  println it.number + " | " + it.result
}
return`
if `result` is `FAILURE`, then you can delete it (or you can skip the first failure, delete the rest, just add a flag. 
I don't use multibranch, but am sure there's a property with the branch you can test and iterate on too. You just need to resolve that property.

Comment: Thank you! You got me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solution below:

```
success {
    script {
        try {
            Hudson.instance.getItemByFullName(JOB_NAME).builds.each {
                if(it.result == hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) {
                    println 'Deleting build number ' + it.number
                    it.delete()
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException) {
        }
    }
}
```